# A functional equation that satisfies condition $f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: functions

does there exist any $f(x)$ that satisfies $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(x)\geq0$;for any positive integer value of x for which if **x** has digit '6' at the one's then f(x)=0 and $f(1920)=420$?

I have tried hard to find a function which satisfies the above condition.
I have to use this fact:

***"All the numbers which have digit '6' at the one's place if divided by 6 has remainder of 4 or 2 or it is divisible by 6. If the number is divisible by 6 and has digit '6' at the one's place then the quotient follows arithmetic sequence (1,6,11,16.......);As for the remainder '4' the quotient follows the sequence (2,5,8......); and for the remainder '2' the quotient follows the sequence (3,6,9......);"***

But couldn't come with something.

Comment: Is $x$ an integer here, or a real number, or what?

Comment: ooops sorry i forgot to add the other conditions. $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(1920)=420$

Comment: Well... that **completely** changes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming the function is just on the positive integers* (*otherwise $f(0)$ cannot be defined since $f(0)+420=f(0\cdot 1920)=f(0)=f(0\cdot 1920^2)=f(0)+840$*)

---

From $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ and from specific values we learn that $f(1920)=f(96)+f(20)=f(20)=420=2f(2)+f(5)$.  We also learn that $f(6)=f(2)+f(3)$ and since $f(2)\geq 0$ and $f(3)\geq 0$ this implies that $f(2)=0$ implying $f(5)=420$.  There doesn't appear to be many if any other major clues as to what we can do here, so we can start building our function.

Let $f(x) = 420\cdot k$ where $k = \max\{n\in\Bbb N~:~5^n\mid x\}$

Recognize that this has all of the desired properties.  For any $x$ which has a ones digit equal to $6$ we have $f(x)=0$ since $5\mid x$ if and only if the ones digit is equal to $0$ or $5$.  Further $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ since if $k_1$ is the largest exponent of a power of $5$ dividing evenly into $x$ and $k_2$ is the largest exponent of a power of $5$ dividing evenly into $y$ it follows that the largest exponent of a power of $5$ dividing evenly into $xy$ is going to be $k_1+k_2$.

Comment: so that means $k$ would be at least 1 if $x$ is divisible by 5. and if $x$ can not be divisible by 5 then the value would be 0?

Comment: Yes.  Any number not divisible by $5$ is still divisible by $5^0$.